# Monitor VMware 5.5 ESXi Storage vMotion Performance

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter, vmotion

Is there any way to monitor the performance of a storage vmotion while it is in progress?  I would like to see something like a kb/s number.  Anything other than just the basic % complete number you see in the vSphere Client.

Comment: What type of storage do you have? What type of physical networking do you have?

Comment: I am copying from an OpenFiler server connected via iSCSI to an HP StoreVirtual VSA network RAID 10 cluster.  Everything is connected via gigabit ethernet.

Comment: You could probably set up port monitoring/mirroring on your switch and run a packet capture to determine the start/stop times and throughput/transfer rate of the migration.

Comment: @joeqwerty: Yeah, but that would show all traffic to/from those iSCSI links with no way to differentiate what is part of the svMotion and what is other data.  I could look at the performance graphs for the same information.  Nothing seems to be able to isolate the performance of just the svMotion move.

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll just have to wait the process out in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As ewwhite says there's little through the GUI but if you were to look at the affected host's log files I think you could essentially follow the process through from start to end. What I will say however is that ESXi logs are DETAILED in the extreme, be prepared to spend a lot of time trawling through them - VMWare Log Insight will help you if you're interested however.

Comment: I thought about this and I have seen articles regarding using the logs to trace svMotion.  But, the log entries tend to be created at distinct steps during the process whereas I am looking for the performance of each individual file copy operation.  Sort of like what you get when you copy a bunch of files and show the details in Windows 7/8/10.

Comment: again I've not log-trawled this myself but I'd be surprised if there wasn't at least some hint you could use?